# Starts with "S" and used on submarines

Tags: riddle, word

> I start with the letter "S".
> I have something to do with missiles and water.
> I am commonly used on submarines and production/power plants.
> I am some sort of storage. 
> I have 4 letters.
>
> What am I?

This is a riddle a friend of mine sent, and I just can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: SSSSSssssssssssmokin' :P

Comment: At first, I thought it was [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com)$[$fnyg$]$ (as it is also some kind of storage when putting it on food) but the "missiles" part did not entirely fit.

Comment: Reminded me of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPUHY9b5TxY

Comment: @ManojKumar well someone has a good taste in movies ;)

Comment: Suranium?wait something wrong

Answer (score 24):

(Updated!)  You might be

> a **Silo**

I start with the letter "S".

> Yup.

I have something to do with missiles and water.

> Missile silos.
>  Also water silos - ["A water silo is a giant barrel that can contain a huge quantity of water. The water stored in a water silo can be used for various purposes."](https://www.buwatec.com/water-silo/)

I am commonly used on submarines and production/power plants.

> Missile subs have silos.  Subs also carry water in holding tanks, both for drinking and for ballast.
>  [Production/power plants keep water in silos for various purposes.](https://www.fishertank.com/industries-served/power)

I am some sort of storage

> Yup

I have 4 letters.

> Yup

Comment: I thought about that too, but it isn't "steam".

Comment: @MrPi Make sure to go to [this website, Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) and write down what you would say in the comments, in the upper box. The site would then convert your message to a secret code; for example, *Hello!* becomes *Uryyb!*. Once you have written what you have to say, copy-and-paste the secret code and put it in Rot13[**here**]. This will let users know where to find your comment, but it also allows for users to decide whether they want to read it or not (because it might contain spoilers). I suggest you should start using Rot13 comments for your future puzzles :)

Comment: @user477343 Not every comment needs rot13. For example, MrPi could have simply said "I thought about that too, but this isn't the answer." - no spoiler needed. Rot13 is a (poor) compromise that allows people to conceal information that would otherwise give away the answer. But there are certainly other ways:  Ideally, [be a bit cryptic/indirect in your comments, such that anyone (eg. the OP) who already knows the answer would understand your comment, but casual scanners should not](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4651). (See also the userscript mentioned in that answer.)

Comment: @Rubio $\diamondsuit$ ok. Thank you for that. I did not know. I will check out the link :)

Answer (score 10):

I agree with [Rubio's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/68143/36023).

But you could also be

> a **sink**.

I have something to do with missiles and water.

> Just like [loose lips](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_lips_sink_ships), missiles can sink ships (in water).

I am commonly used on submarines and production/power plants.

> Apart from the literal explanation which applies to most places intended for human presence, submarines can dive (sink), and power plants need a [heat sink](https://www.power-technology.com/features/featureinfinite-heat-sink-us-floating-nuclear-design-makes-a-splash-4317446/) to maintain their operating temperature.

I am some sort of storage.

> I have to confess there are some unwashed dishes in my kitchen sink..

I start with the letter "S".
I have 4 letters.

> Yes.

Comment: +1 for "I have to confess there are some unwashed dishes in my kitchen ..."

Answer (score 5):

I start with the letter

> "S". = SALT

I have something to do with missiles and water.

> (SALT MISSLE TREATY)  (SALT WATER).

I am commonly used on submarines and production/power plants

> (SODIUM SALT FOR HEAT TRANSPORT).

I am some sort of storage

> (STORE HEAT IN SALT).

I have 4 letters.

> SALT

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This seems like a pretty good answer. I added [spoilers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers) to your answer so that others won't accidentally see it. Why not [take the tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and earn an easy badge?

Comment: I was thinking of this answer, but I could not find a match with the "missiles and water" part. However, look at [**one of the other answers**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/68141/starts-with-s-and-used-on-submarines/68192#68192) and you will spot the similarity. $(+1)$ nonetheless :)

Comment: Why is this one upvoted with the same answers as mine when I answered this first?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it could be

> SUMP

As,

> it is for storage of oil / water etc. and also used in warfare equipment. It is of 4 letters and starts with a S.

Comment: Mea Culpa yayyy :D

Answer (score 3):

the answer to this question is

> 'sump' (I am a former NAVY submarine contract worker).

Comment: How does it fit with missiles?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I agree, you need to explain in a little more detail how this fits each line of the riddle. You might be a former Navy submarine contract worker, but most of us here aren't, so the connection isn't as obvious.

Comment: I feel like the downvotes on this answer are inappropriate - he is a new user and has not had appropriate time to come back and correct his answer.

Comment: i thought so too. There is a " missile-sump effect " @ChrisCudmore

Answer (score 2):

Do you need a

> Solution?
>  Missiles are fired from a submarine when a shooting "solution" is found.
>  Power production uses all types of solutions, [here's an instance.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolysis_of_water)

Comment: No that's not it.

Answer (score 2):

Taking user477343's comment and making it an answer (because I thought this word too):

You could be:

> SALT

I start with the letter "S".

> Salt does

I have something to do with missiles

> **S**trategic **A**rms **L**imitation **T**alks (**SALT**) were about limiting the number of nuclear missiles through a treaty.

and water.

> Most water in the world is saltwater.

I am commonly used on submarines

> Not sure... In the dining area?

and production/power plants.

> There are power plants based on saltwater heating.  There is something called a molten salt power plant.

I am some sort of storage.

> Salt packing of meat (and other products) is a storage method.

I have 4 letters.

> Salt has 4 letters

Answer (score 0):

Could you also be

> **Sand**?

`I start with the letter "S".`

> Indeed.

`I have something to do with missiles and water.`

> There is a place known as the [**The White** ***Sands*** **Missile Range**](https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/449089main_White_Sands_Missile_Range_Fact_Sheet.pdf) and at the **beach**, you will find **sand and water**. (Also, water has waves, and so does sand; i.e., [**sand dunes**](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/guest-blogs/2014/0219-sand-waves-in-the-desert.html).)

`I am commonly used on submarines and production/power plants.`

> Not too sure about this one. Perhaps something in relation to [submarine **sand waves**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11707-016-0571-6)?

`I am some sort of storage.`

> Not too sure about this one, either, but sand is **stored** in an [**hourglass**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hourglass).

`I have four letters.`

> $$\verb|S|\;\verb|A|\;\verb|N|\;\verb|D|$$

`What am I?`

> **Sand**, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

How about

> silo.

I don't know if submarines call them that for

> SLBMs

but worth a shot.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! First of all, please make sure that your answer hasn't already been posted before posting. Secondly, it's customary to use spoiler tags to avoid potentially spoling the solution for anyone who wants to have a go at the puzzle themselves; I've added those in for you. Thirdly, this could use a bit more explanation as to how it matches each line of the riddle.

Answer (score 0):

> SEALs:  "Submarine Armament - SEALs (SSGN - Dry Deck Shelters). SSGNs can carry two Dry Deck Shelters (DDS), 9-foot diameter chambers attached to the top of the Missile Deck. Each DDS has the ability to carry one SEAL Delivery Vehicle (SDV) or several RIBs (inflatable speedboats - more on that tomorrow). But normally, DDS's carry SDVs. An SDV is a 4-man mini-sub capable of being launched from the DDS while the SSGN loiters off the coast submerged. The team of SEALs traverses toward shore submerged in their SDV, returning when their mission is accomplished." - via http://www.rickcampbellauthor.com/styled/index.html

Starts with S
Has to do with missiles and water
Found with submarines, dunno about power plants though
I mean, it can store something
is four letters